# Decidability of the monadic second-order theory of a class of finite structures

Tags: reference-request, lo.logic, finite-model-theory

Let $L$ be the set of sentences in some logic.  I am interested in cases where $L$ is the set of sentences in monadic second-order logic, or it is its $\Pi^1_1$ fragment.  Let $K$ be a class of finite structures.  The *theory* $\mathrm{Th}_L(K)$ of $K$ is the set of sentences $\phi$ such that $\forall M \in K$ $M \models \phi$.  I am interested in decidability of $\mathrm{Th}_L(K)$.

For what kind of class $K$ is this known?  What are important / deep techniques here?  What is a good source to learn the results and the techniques?

Comment: A starting point: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Courcelle's_theorem

Comment: This question asks for reference on MSO as well. So it may be useful to you:  https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2696251/120721